# How to understand where you put your widgets in android layouts programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm currently making a simple game with the surfaceview but I find it hard to position the buttons or texts within the Relative layout programmatically in android.  For example, in the sample below Im setting the relativelayouts with texts in a relative layout, and I want to set it to the right side of the screen with few margins to the right. How should I understand where I'm positioning the contents ? And are there some tips on positioning contents programmatically?

```
RelativeLayout Rs = new RelativeLayout(this);
        Rs.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn);
        Rs.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Regame.addView(RR,400,150);
        Rs.setX(0);
        txt= new TextView(this);
```

Comment: Why not use the graphical layout editor http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html#graphical-editor ? About positioning programatically if you are using relative layout you have to take into account the parents . Can you tell more about your problem and why you need to tackle this programatically?

Comment: Well, I'm making a 2D scrolling game with SurfaceView, therefore, I must draw the contents programmatically.  I wish there was some simple way.

Comment: If you are using SurfaceView and know the surface dimensions couldn't you draw directly on the canvas?

Comment: You are right. But sometimes the position turns out to be something unexpected. That is why I thought if there are some good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would be sufficient if you accessed the canvas from within the surfaceView.Probably would be more efficient if you used [onSizeChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))
for the width and height but i guess the canvas getWidth and getHeight would suffice.Also my example is just drawing once the surface is created, you'll have to make your own update logic.Also i am ditching the relative layout but i think this could suffice your needs:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
    protected SurfaceHolder holder;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {                
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                onDraw(c);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        paint.setTextSize(20); 
        int width=canvas.getWidth();
        int height=canvas.getHeight();
        //Just for example
        int desiredHeight=height/2;
        int desiredMargin=10;
        String desiredText="Some text";
        int textWidth=Math.round(paint.measureText(desiredText));
        int desiredWidth=width-textWidth-desiredMargin;
        canvas.drawText(desiredText, desiredWidth,desiredHeight, paint);
    }
}
```